# QlikView: Displaying Charts in Grouped Style

Tags: qlikview

I created a bar chart with 3 dimensions:

- Year
- Quarter
- Senario

And I have one expression (Sum(Sales)).

Year, Quarter, and Scenario are displayed on the X axis.
The problem is Scenario bars is displayed in Stacked and not in Grouped style. In the Properties->Stlye->Subtype window, the Grouped and Stacked options are grayed out - the system does not allow me to choose either one of them. 
How can I display Scenarios in Grouped stlye?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be QV cannot handle more than 2 dimensions without stacking.

I would suggest to either create a new dimension variable (for example Year & Quarter) so that you only have 2 dimension variables (Year&Quarter and Region):

[image: Chart with a Year&Quarter dimension to allow bar grouping.]

Or to create a drill down group on Year -> Quarter.

In the end, I guess that it will be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 dimensions QlikView doesn't know which one to stack so removes the option.

So to solve this it groups the second dimension and stacks the 3rd
Example:
[image]

[image]

So if you switch the dimensions around I imagine you can get what you want. Unless you want Scenarios to stack and Quarters to stack, that is not possible , but I donn't know that the resultant graph would make sense.

Comment: In reference to your pictures, I am trying to get the bars to be not stacked on top of each outher, but o be next to each other. Nothing should be stacked in the chart.

Comment: Can you draw that graph in excel and post an example? I still don't understand what we are trying to achieve or how that would be read